# Topology data analysis - faster algorithm

Tags: gn.general-topology, homological-algebra, algorithms, data-analysis

The Topology Data Analysis uses the Mapper algorithm, but computational complexity is not good. Is there an alternative algorithm for algorithm Mapper? Is there an algorithm that works faster?

Comment: I'm guessing you're referring to the Mapper algorithm of Singh, Mémoli and Carlsson from this paper https://www.ayasdi.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Topological_Methods_for_the_Analysis_of_High_Dimensional_Data_Sets_and_3D_Object_Recognition.pdf . It would help if you edited some more background into your question and were more precise about your needs.

Comment: Yes. Computational cost is big:  at some point, if computing one barcode / persistence diagram is rather ok, computing thousand of them, and then compute pairwise distances between them etc ... is a bit complicated. That is computational problem. What is Time computational complexity for Mapper?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check out https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.03660
It describes a way to execute in parallel Mapper.